# Problem with SelectKBest method in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to solve a problem where I use KNN algorithm for classification. While using pipeline, I decided to add `SelectKBest` but I get the error below :

> All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform.

I don't know if I can use this selection algorithm with KNN. But I tried with SVM as well and got the same result. Here is my code :

```
sel = SelectKBest('chi2',k = 3)
clf = kn()
s = ss()
step = [('scaler', s), ('kn', clf), ('sel',sel)]
pipeline = Pipeline(step)
parameter = {'kn__n_neighbors':range(1,40,1), 'kn__weights':['uniform','distance'], 'kn__p':[1,2] }
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0)
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = parameter, cv=kfold, scoring = 'accuracy', n_jobs = -1)
grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the operations in the pipeline, as determined in `steps`, matters; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

> **steps : *list***
>
> List of (name, transform) tuples (implementing fit/transform) that are chained, in the order in which they are chained, with the last object an estimator.

The error is due to adding `SelectKBest` as the *last* element of your pipeline:

```
step = [('scaler', s), ('kn', clf), ('sel',sel)]
```

which is not an estimator (it is a transformer), as well as to your intermediate step `kn` not being a transformer.

I guess you don't really want to perform feature selection *after* you have fitted the model...

Change it to:

```
step = [('scaler', s), ('sel', sel), ('kn', clf)]
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't think the order of the pipeline is important but then, I found out the last member of the pipeline has to be able to fit/transform. I changed the order of the pipeline by making clf the last. Problem is solved.

Comment: Actually, the last item of the pipeline has to be an estimator (i.e. regressor/classifier); it is the *intermediate* items that have to implement fit & transform.